# Right click on gnome desktop does not work - ubuntu 19.04 Gnome flashback

Tags: mouse, gnome-flashback

It does not matter if I am using BT mouse or touchpad. After upgrade to 19.04 (gnome flashback) stopped to show right click menu on desktop. In apps and file manager all works fine. Any idea what can be wrong?

Edit:
Right click works also in Unity.

Edit2:
Clean install and switching to gnome flashback did not make the difference. Menu does not show.
As pointed by muktupavels in comments it looks like it is a feature...

Comment: Might be a specific issue with your configuration. I am also on 19.04, but I have a right-click menu.

Comment: I am upgrading Ubuntu from 14.10. Could be a sign to reinstall from scratch :)

Comment: For sure, that will likely be the cause. In that case, your question probably should be closed again - you may want to delete it because it will be of no help to future users.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. I did clean reinstall and right-click on Desktop does not work in gnome-flashback.

Comment: Please update your question by editing it. If you also have the issue with a fresh installation, then for sure this is a valid question. Also do some testing and provide the info by editing your question. For example, does it also happen in a regular default Ubuntu session? What did you do to get your current configuration "gnome flashback"?

Comment: Desktop icons used to be handled by nautilus. That is no longer the case! There is no upstream solution for GNOME Flashback right now. As workaround you can try to use nemo-desktop (if I am not wrong that is what Unity is using).

Comment: I'm seconding this report.  Looks like nemo-desktop is really designed to work with Cinnamon, leaving a number of other issues with Gnome Flashback.  Looks like it's time to jump ship to Ubuntu Mate or another variant...